# how to form redis cluster using 3 master nodes and 3 slave nodes

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

I m new to redis. i want to create redis cluster using 3 master nodes and 3 slave nodes.
First i installed redis-server on all the three linux systems.
Redis-server version that got installed is 4.0.9
I Edited /etc/redis/redis.conf file initiall like as below
bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.X.XX
protected-mode no
port 6379
pidfile /var/run/redis_6379.pid
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-6379.conf
cluster-node-timeout 15000

with these changes redis server stopped running and i couldn't correct it back so i uninstalled and installed it back again. Now to create cluter i followed below procedures like
mkdir cluster
cd cluster

vi redis_master1.conf

bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.X.XX
protected-mode no
port 6380
pidfile /var/run/redis_6380.pid
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-6380.conf
cluster-node-timeout 15000

vi redis_slave1.conf

bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.X.XX
protected-mode no
port 6381
pidfile /var/run/redis_6381.pid
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-6381.conf
cluster-node-timeout 15000

There is change in ip address and port num in respective systems accordingly
Now, when i gave redis-cli --cluster create 192.168.X.XX:6380 192.168.Y.YY:6381 192.168.Z.ZZ:6382 --cluster-replicas 1

i get the following error
Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--cluster'

My Quetions are

1. Does Open source Redis supports cluster formation?
2. Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your 2 questions.

1. Yes, open source Redis does provide cluster capability
2. In your cluster create command, you have to connect to one of the node and then pass the --cluter create argument like:

> redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 7000 --cluster create 127.0.0.1:7000
> 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005 --cluster-replicas 1

In the above command, the assumption is that redis is **installed and running** on all the 6 nodes.

For complete steps you can follow my [github link](https://github.com/ankitforcodes/redis/blob/1eb812ef7b69b6c9a6c6eae487436b99a32a232c/clusters/cluster.txt)